# How to select two columns from one table that are connected to a column in another table in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example I have two tables A and B. In table A I store ids for departure and arrival days. In B I have `day_id` which is primary key and in `day_name` I have things like: Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc.

[See the picture of how the table should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot0RP.png)

My question is how do I select names for both departure and arrival days in one select statement?

I want to get something like this in SQL Developer:

[The picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wIy7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to alias B and join to it twice in your select statement. I've done a very basic create for the two tables, inserted some data and put together a select, I'm not sure if this is what you're after?

```
create table A (
departure_day_id int,
arrival_day_id int
)

create table B (
day_id int,
day_name varchar(10)
)

insert into B
select 1, 'Monday'

insert into B
select 2, 'Tuesday'

insert into A
select 1, 2

select A.arrival_day_id, B1.day_name, A.departure_day_id, B2.day_name
from A inner join B as B1
        on A.arrival_day_id = B1.day_id
    inner join B as B2
        on A.departure_day_id = B2.day_id
```

Results are as follows:

> 2, Tuesday, 1, Monday

Comment: That's exactly what I want but unfortunately this code doesn't seem to work. Thank you anyway)

Comment: I'm sorry, I only noticed after I responded that you're doing this in Oracle and I'm no longer familiar with the syntactical differences between MSSQL and Oracle's SQL syntax that would prevent this from working. Sorry about that.

Comment: The syntax seems correct, I highly doubt this would not work on an Oracle database. @Dave, what error are you getting for the `select` statement?

Comment: Apparently `as` was causing me problems. It should not be used in this statement. The rest is correct. Thank you!